# Qt Qstring <not accessible> and SIGSEGV segmantation fault

Tags: c++, qt

I'm seeing a strange segmentation fault when accessing a QString type struct member from GET_STATION_MODEL_PARAMS_t. The execution is stopped at `**`:

code:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "hradcontroller.h"
#include "hradAPI.h"

#define TAG "HRAD_CONTROLLER:\0"
#define HRAD_API_VERSION        "2"
#define MANUFACTURER_KEY        "abcde12345"

typedef struct registerDeviceParams{
    QString brand; 
    QString device;
    QString manufacturer;
    QString model;
    QString serial;
    QString ibd; 
    QString ibkey;
    QString version;
    QString track;

    registerDeviceCB_t cbFn;
}REGISTER_DEVICE_PARAMS_t;

typedef struct getStationModelParams{
    int stationID;
    QString ibd;
    QString ibkey;
    QString version;
    QString track;

    getStationModelCB_t cbFn;

    GET_STATION_MODEL_RESPONSE_t* resp;
 }GET_STATION_MODEL_PARAMS_t;

HRAD *hbr = new HRAD();

void registerDevice(){
    REGISTER_DEVICE_PARAMS_t params;
    params.brand = "brand";
    params.device = "TI-J6";
    params.manufacturer = "manuf";
    params.model = "EVK";
    params.ibkey = MANUFACTURER_KEY;
    params.serial = "abcde12345";
    params.version = HRAD_API_VERSION;
    params.track = "true";
    params.cbFn = deviceRegisteredCB;

    hbr->registerDevice(&params);
}

 void getStationModel(int id){
    GET_STATION_MODEL_PARAMS_t params;
    params.stationID = id;
    params.ibd = hbr->getId();
    params.ibkey = "abdef";
    params.version = "2";
**  params.track = "false";  //SIGSEGV segmantation fault here
    params.cbFn = stationModelAvailableCB;

    params.resp = &g_StationModel;
}

void deviceRegisteredCB(QString ibd){
    qDebug() << TAG << "Device Registered: ibd = " << ibd;

    getStationModel(currentPublicStationID);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    /* Register ourselves to HRAD Server */

    registerDevice();
}
```

Values just before the seg. fault:

[image]

If you notice "track" is "not accessible" while debugging and this causes crash.

I modified GET_STATION_MODEL_PARAMS_t like this:

```
typedef struct getStationModelParams{
    int stationID;
    QString foo; //dummy variable.
    QString ibd;
    QString ibkey;
    QString version; //seg. fault here now
    QString track;

    getStationModelCB_t cbFn;

    GET_STATION_MODEL_RESPONSE_t* resp;
 }GET_STATION_MODEL_PARAMS_t;
```

And values became like this:
[image]

Now "version" is also "not accessible".

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks.

Update 1:

Tools:

Qt Creator 3.4.1 (ubuntu 14.04)

Qt 5.4.2 (GCC 4.6.1, 64 bit)

Comment: It's a single thread application? you use same struct in different places?

Comment: @Jepessen Yes, this is a single threaded app. In fact, getStationModel() is called almost immediately as soon as 'MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)'  is called.

Comment: This is a classic case of writing over memory that doesn't belong to you. The `QStrings` in the structure are destroyed, their d-pointers (the PIMPL idiom) point to unallocated or unreadable addresses. The debugger tells you as much.

Comment: **Have you deleted the build folder and re-built the application?**

Comment: Yes, I did delete the build folder and rebuilt the app. Same thing.

Comment: Whoever voted it down, please give the reason why or provide an answer.

Comment: The code that you posted, while a horrible abomination (this is C++, not C!), is correct on its own. There's no way to answer your question. Unanswerable questions are off topic - they help no one, neither you nor others. You'll need to start minimizing your code: first, concatenate all code into a single `main.cpp` with `#include "main.moc"` at the end, in a new project. Then start removing unnecessary things until what remains is the minimum necessary to crash. That will be your answer - without having to ask anybody.

Comment: HRAD is a c++ class. Anyways, I'll clean up and start everything from scratch to debug.

Comment: You do not need nor should clean up and start everything from scratch. Copy your project's sources to another folder. Concatenate everything (all .h and .cpp files) to a single `main.cpp` file with `#include "main.moc"` as the last line. Start removing code until what's left is the minimum needed to crash. At that point you either know what's wrong, or you post `main.cpp` here, and someone will quickly tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: This is why you really need to post all the code needed to reproduce the crash.

Your code works - no crashes. Your question is thus answered, even if the answer is completely useless to you, and everyone else too. **Don't ask questions that can only be answered in a way that can't help you.**

The only thing that stands out in your code, besides it being a horrible C abomination with no place in modern C++, is that the HRAD instance is created before `main` starts executing. Depending on what HRAD's constructor is doing, this might be a bad thing.

But let's see if we can fix your code up some, to guide you to write safer code.

### Old Code

First, let's start with your code verbatim, with some additions at the beginning and end to get it to compile and execute.

**You should have provided all that in your question - with enough of "other stuff" to crash.** The below, assuming that it crashed or otherwise reproduced your problem, would be considered an [sscce](http://sscce.org) and make your question valuable to the community.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

typedef void (*registerDeviceCB_t)(QString);
typedef void (*getStationModelCB_t)();
typedef struct getStationModelResponse {} GET_STATION_MODEL_RESPONSE_t;
void deviceRegisteredCB(QString);
void stationModelAvailableCB() {}

typedef struct registerDeviceParams REGISTER_DEVICE_PARAMS_t;
struct HRAD {
   void registerDevice(REGISTER_DEVICE_PARAMS_t*);
   QString getId() { return QString(); }
};

GET_STATION_MODEL_RESPONSE_t g_StationModel;
int currentPublicStationID = 1;

void registerDevice();
void getStationModel(int);
int main()
{
   registerDevice();
   getStationModel(0);
   return 0;
}

// Your code verbatim beyond this point
```

Your code, copy-pasted for reference (with apparently irrelevant `MainWindow` removed):

```
#define TAG "HRAD_CONTROLLER:\0"
#define HRAD_API_VERSION        "2"
#define MANUFACTURER_KEY        "abcde12345"

typedef struct registerDeviceParams{
   QString brand;
   QString device;
   QString manufacturer;
   QString model;
   QString serial;
   QString ibd;
   QString ibkey;
   QString version;
   QString track;

   registerDeviceCB_t cbFn;
}REGISTER_DEVICE_PARAMS_t;

typedef struct getStationModelParams{
   int stationID;
   QString ibd;
   QString ibkey;
   QString version;
   QString track;

   getStationModelCB_t cbFn;

   GET_STATION_MODEL_RESPONSE_t* resp;
}GET_STATION_MODEL_PARAMS_t;

HRAD *hbr = new HRAD();

void registerDevice(){
   REGISTER_DEVICE_PARAMS_t params;
   params.brand = "brand";
   params.device = "TI-J6";
   params.manufacturer = "manuf";
   params.model = "EVK";
   params.ibkey = MANUFACTURER_KEY;
   params.serial = "abcde12345";
   params.version = HRAD_API_VERSION;
   params.track = "true";
   params.cbFn = deviceRegisteredCB;

   hbr->registerDevice(&params);
}

void getStationModel(int id){
   GET_STATION_MODEL_PARAMS_t params;
   params.stationID = id;
   params.ibd = hbr->getId();
   params.ibkey = "abdef";
   params.version = "2";
   params.track = "false";  //SIGSEGV segmantation fault here
   params.cbFn = stationModelAvailableCB;

   params.resp = &g_StationModel;
}

void deviceRegisteredCB(QString ibd){
   qDebug() << TAG << "Device Registered: ibd = " << ibd;

   getStationModel(currentPublicStationID);
}

// End of verbatim code
```

And, finally, the implementation of `registerDevice`:

```
void HRAD::registerDevice(REGISTER_DEVICE_PARAMS_t* params) {
   params->cbFn("some ibd");
}
```

These three pieces, when put into a `main.cpp`, will compile, run, and properly invoke the callback. To wit:

```
Starting bad-c-aargh-31542746...
HRAD_CONTROLLER: Device Registered: ibd =  "some ibd"
bad-c-aargh-31542746 exited with code 0
```

### Rework

It seems that you're using callbacks and passing values via pointers, as you would in C. We'll get rid of the C typedefs that are unnecessary in C++, and we will leverage C++11's features to make the callbacks much more usable.

As above, the code below is merely interspersed with the commentary. You could copy-paste it to a `main.cpp`, remove the commentary, compile it and run. It is complete.

First, let's include the `functional` header to bring in `std::function`, and we shall get rid of C-style macros:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <functional>

const QString TAG = QStringLiteral("HRAD_CONTROLLER:");
const QString HRAD_API_VERSION = QStringLiteral("2");
const QString MANUFACTURER_KEY = QStringLiteral("abcde12345");
```

Then we shall define the structures used to pass parameters to `HRAD` methods, and to obtain the responses from these methods:

```
struct RegisterDeviceParams {
   QString brand;
   QString device;
   QString manufacturer;
   QString model;
   QString serial;
   QString ibd;
   QString ibkey;
   QString version;
   QString track;
};

struct GetStationModelParams {
   int stationID;
   QString ibd;
   QString ibkey;
   QString version;
   QString track;
};

struct GetStationModelReponse {};
```

We can then implement a skeleton `HRAD` class. The parameters are passed as const references. The *optional* callbacks can be compatible lambdas, functor instances, function pointers, etc. The provision of default-constructed values makes them optional. You can leave them out from a call, the compiler will use the defaults instead. The `currentPublicStationID`, presumably a global variable, belongs in `HRAD`, too.

```
class HRAD {
public:
   void registerDevice(const RegisterDeviceParams &,
                       const std::function<void(const QString & ibd)> & cb
                       = std::function<void(const QString&)>()) {
      cb("some ibd");
   }

   void getStationModel(const GetStationModelParams &,
                        const std::function<void(const GetStationModelReponse &)> & cb
                        = std::function<void(const GetStationModelReponse&)>()) {
      GetStationModelReponse response;
      cb(response);
   }

   QString getId() { return "some id"; }
   int currentPublicStationID;
   HRAD() : currentPublicStationID(1) {}
};
```

The global instance of `HRAD` is defined using the `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC` macro. It will be instantiated, thread-safely, upon first use. It acts as a pointer - to get the global instance, you should use the `->` operator.

```
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(HRAD, hbr) // no semicolon needed
```

The `getStationModel` and `registerDevice` functions will use lambda syntax to instantiate the callbacks on the spot. Of course if the callbacks were more complex, you could put them in stand-alone functions or methods.

```
void getStationModel(int id){
   GetStationModelParams params;
   params.stationID = id;
   params.ibd = hbr->getId();
   params.ibkey = "abdef";
   params.version = "2";
   params.track = "false";

   hbr->getStationModel(params, [](const GetStationModelReponse&){
      qDebug() << "got station model";
   });
}

void registerDevice(){
   RegisterDeviceParams params;
   params.brand = "brand";
   params.device = "TI-J6";
   params.manufacturer = "manuf";
   params.model = "EVK";
   params.ibkey = MANUFACTURER_KEY;
   params.serial = "abcde12345";
   params.version = HRAD_API_VERSION;
   params.track = "true";

   hbr->registerDevice(params, [](const QString & ibd){
      qDebug() << TAG << "Device Registered: ibd = " << ibd;
      getStationModel(hbr->currentPublicStationID);
   });
}
```

Finally, we call `registerDevice` from main:

```
int main()
{
   registerDevice();
   return 0;
}
```

This code works, and produces the following output:

```
Starting bad-c-aargh-31542746...
"HRAD_CONTROLLER:" Device Registered: ibd =  "some ibd"
got station model
bad-c-aargh-31542746 exited with code 0
```

Note the absence of any manual memory management. Raw pointers aren't used either - neither as parameters, nor as members.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I admit I'm a primarily C programmer, so think like C, rarely I need to use C++, so don't know all its features and tools. And I should have posted more code, but there were some parts I couldn't share, so needed to remove them.

Comment: @rockford98 C++11 is an entirely different language than C. If you try to write C++11 as you would C, you'll end up shooting yourself in the foot. Repeatedly. I suggest the reading of the most recent edition (4th) of Strostrup's "The C++ Programming Language".